# undefined local variable or method `edit_user_registration_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, devise

I want to allow users to change their passwords. When i give the below link it gives undefined local variable or method `edit_user_registration_path' for error.

```
<li><%= link_to 'Change Password', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
```

My routes:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :dashboard_users
  resources :vendors
  resources :dashboard_users
  resources :assessments
  resources :projects
  resources :release_cycles
  resources :home
  resources :project_vendor
  resources :project_maturity_score_views
  resources :project_maturity_scores do
  collection do
    get :plan
    get :develop
    get :test
    get :release
    get :operations
    post :plan
    post :develop
    post :test
    post :release
    post :operations
  end
end

  get '/dashboard' => 'home#dashboard', :as => 'dashboard_users/sign_in'

  #get 'release_cycle/vendor_search'

  match '/release_cycles/new' => 'release_cycles#new', via: [:get, :post]
  match '/assessments/new' => 'assessments#new', via: [:get, :post]


    as :dashboard_users do
      get 'dashboard_users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'    
      put 'dashboard_users/:id' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'            
    end
```

Comment: Missing template dashboard_users/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/vadmin/project work/Dashboard_CD/app/views" * "/home/vadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"

Comment: and please show output of: `rake routes |grep registation`

Comment: Couldn't find DashboardUser with 'user_id'=edit @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: @Rajkumar is it the output for `rake routes |grep registation`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71dd28bcae06d6568bb5 @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: so that is your correct path: `edit_dashboard_user_registration_path`, but, I believe that the url has been constricted of edit+dashboard_user+registration. please expand the block of `as :dashboard_users do` to the root, or scope if required

Comment: In what file i want to change?@МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: That is `config/routes.rb`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/025631045aacc6838dba@МалъСкрылевъ